# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket. I want to connect to REMOTE db

Tags: ruby

This is my code.
I want to connect to **remote** database

```
require 'bundler/setup' 
    #require "mysql"
    #require 'mysql2'
    #require "active_record"

Bundler.require



@db_host  = ENV["HOST"]
@db_user  = ENV["USER"]
@db_pass  = ENV['PASSWORD']
@db_name = "db_name"

require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql2',
  :database => @db_name,
  :username => @db_user,
  :password => @db_pass,
  :host     => @db_host)


class ConversionRate < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ConversionRateMonthly < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "conversion_rates_monthly"
end

class KdpReport < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class SalesCalculator 
    def run

        p KdpReport.count

    end 

end 

calculator = SalesCalculator.new
calculator.run
```

But I get this error:

> /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

It is strange but yesterday my code worked. what may be wrong? I want to connect to remote db, not local. And btw I use ruby without rails.

Comment: print value of your `@db_host` var. I guess it's nil or point to `localhost`

Comment: @unkmas thanks man! I was using ubuntu that is shipped with windows 10, so it seems like all my env vars erased from yesterday

Comment: Added answer. Please accept it to close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is in empty environment var `ENV["HOST"]`.

When host, passed to `ActiveRecord` is `nil` or equl to string `localhost` - AR will try to connect to db using socket.

Comment: This was it. A good practice is to use `ENV.fetch( "HOST" )` so that if the key doesn't exist, it'll throw an exception instead of just returning `nil`, and send you down a rabbit hole chasing a red herring.